# How to use listpickerflyout in windows phone 8.1 using MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, mvvm-light

I am looking for an example of how can i use listpickerflyout in windows phone 8.1 in MVVM Light. My requirement is to show a list to user e.g country list where user can pick one of the country. and selected country is shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got the solution :) just need to add the button and than add listpickerflyout in xaml and bind the item source of the flyout and button content property. here is how

```
<Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="{Binding SelectedCountry.Name, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <ListPickerFlyout ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" 
                          Placement="Full" 
                          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCountry, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                          DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```